# What's the difference between "Access to moderator tools" and being a moderator?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to get the difference between "Access to moderator tools" and being a moderator,

Does moderator have more privileges than that?

Comment: I believe we do yes... also we get this special diamond... honestly though I'm glad we're getting more 10k users as I've not really been active for some time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terminology is fairly ambiguous. Back in the day "moderating" frequently referred to using the 10k tools, and "♦ moderator" was for elected mods. Now "moderators" typically refers to ♦ mods. You'll occasionally see "pseudo-mods" used to refer to 10k users as well, but that's pretty much died out too.

As for privileges, see [What's the difference between a moderator and someone who has access to moderator tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136890/whats-the-difference-between-a-moderator-and-someone-who-has-access-to-moderato) on the main meta. In theory 10k users can do everything that doesn't require access to sensitive data. ♦ mods don't need to vote to perform user actions, and have a few extra things they can do that users can't do at all. They also have access to a bunch of random site data, which is the reason for the [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement), but the hope is [regular users can do almost anything](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)